# XAML Layout cropped at bottom. Lumia 640

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

The XAML layout of Windows Phone 8.1 (Universal) app gets cropped by approximately 30 pixels at the bottom in Lumia 640. It works without cropping for all other models. I guess it is because Lumia 640 comes with onscreen buttons. (Start, back and search)

If yes, what is correct way to adapt my XAML layout to this particular scenario?
Is there a way to test this scenario in Emulator?

Comment: Have you tried testing on a WVGA emulator device (typically the first one in the list)? My guess is you have designed your app for a 16:9 display, but many phones are 15:9.

Comment: Is your layout using absolute width/height values?  If so, try using `Auto` and setting `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to needed values.

Answer (score 0):

I think that adding this in your C# code should work:

```
public MainPage()
   {
       this.InitializeComponent();
       Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetDesiredBoundsMode(Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseVisible);
    }
```